# In ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a derivative, what is $\ dx$ and $\ dy$ when separated?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In Schaum's Outline Of Theory And Problems Of Partial Differential Equations, equations like these are quite common:
\begin{align}
a\,dy^2-2b \,dx\cdot dy+c\,dx^2=0\\
a^2 dt^2-dx^2=0
\end{align}

I have not seen this way of specifying ODE's in the past and the syntax doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

- Multiplying and dividing by differentials is always a neat trick for the inverse function, but what does it actually mean to not divide afterwards?
- What does it mean to have an ODE in this differential form rather than the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ form?
- Is there an advantage to this syntax?
- Can one solve ODEs directly in this differential form without first going through the derivative form?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to regard such expressions is as shorthand. (But not the only way---Lutz Lehmann's answer shows how they can be regarded rigorously as differential forms.) For instance, if we divide the first equation through by $dx^2$ then we obtain $a(dy/dx)^2-2b (dy/dx)+c=0$ which is certainly a valid ODE for $y$ as a function of $x$. But we could also have divided by $dy^2$ instead, in which case it would give an ODE for $x$ as a function of $y$. We could also imagine viewing $x,y$ as parametrized by some independent variable $t$, in which case dividing by $dt^2$ gives a constraint on the $t$-derivatives of $x,y$.

Such expressions commonly show up in physics and engineering contexts, where one views $dx,dy$ as standing first for 'infinitesimal' changes/contributions. This is not entirely rigorous, but it can again be taken as shorthand: it allows one to reason in terms of infinitesimal changes rather than rates of change. Another common appearance is in the method of characteristics, where one has $$\frac{dx}{a(x,y,z)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y,z)}=\frac{dz}{c(x,y,z)}$$ as the "parametrization-independent" form of the Lagrange-Charpit equations.

Answer (score 1):

These are not really differential equations, but quadratic forms on the tangent space. The examples here define two lines in the tangent space, two directions.

Now one can ask for continuously differentiable curves that are, in each point, tangent to these directions. In most points that will correspond to the solution of a differential equation, but here it is allowed to switch the independent variable. Or in other words, vertical tangents, e.g., at fold points, are allowed.

But that is just one interpretation of these expressions. The $dx,dy,dt$ could also be infinitesimals, informal or in some modern exact sense it really depends on the context.

Comment: In the book it's specifically mentioned these are ODEs.

Comment: Then they are using the "ordinary" in ODE in a more extended sense than usual. Use some modern textbooks to determine what the current consensus on the subdivision of the field of differential equations is, compared to the state presented in the book. It is usually better to use the current language standards in new communications.